# Talend tRestClient Consume REST API with 1 header

Tags: talend

I'm trying to call a simple 'Hello World' REST API via the **GET** verb. The API is only expecting one HTTP Header, **Accept application/json** which i've set in the Advanced Settings>HTTP Headers of my **tRestClient** component. However, looking at the code tab, Talend seems to automatically create another entry for the contents of the Accept Type dropdown. When i run I’m getting **HTTP 406 Not Acceptable** back because the API is not expecting 2 headers.

I've tested this API with other software and it responds correctly so it must be down to Talend configuration. Anybody know a way around this or had a similar issue they've resolved?

I have screenshots but unfortunately they're being blocked by my firewall at work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tRESTClient` defines its http headers based on the parameters you supply in the component settings. It has an "`Accept Type`" setting, which you can set to "`JSON`", this adds the http header "`Accept: application/json`" (this way you don't have to add it in the http headers section).

[image]

For your use case, you can also use `tREST`, which allows you to have complete control over http headers, it only sends those you set in the http headers section.

Comment: I've tried this but unfortunately the full accept header the API needs is something like Accept: application/sofwarename1.0json so it doesn't work

Comment: Then you need to try with tREST as I suggested, as it gives you control over http headers. Please try and let me know.

Comment: tRest looks more promising thanks - it's giving me a different error but that's one for another thread i think 
 com.sun.jersey cannot be resolved to a type
 com.sun.jersey.client cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: that error could be because you're not using the correct jar.. Can you post another question and I'll look at it ? (If my answer solves your original problem, could you please mark it as accepted).