# Talend tRest component causing compilation problems

Tags: talend

I'm trying to call a simple REST API in Talend. I've tried the **tRestClient** component but ran into problems ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586057/talend-trestclient-consume-rest-api-with-1-header/48586548)). Now i'm trying to use the **tRest** component but get a different error.

**Talend error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    com.sun.jersey cannot be resolved to a type
    com.sun.jersey cannot be resolved to a type
    com.sun.jersey.client cannot be resolved to a variable
    com.sun.jersey cannot be resolved to a type
    com.sun.jersey cannot be resolved to a type
    com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client cannot be resolved to a type
    com.sun.jersey cannot be resolved to a type
    com.sun.jersey cannot be resolved to a type
    com.sun.jersey cannot be resolved to a type
    com.sun.jersey cannot be resolved to a type
```

My Talend job is just a **tRest** into a **tLogRow**. The tRest component is configured with the API call URL, HTTP Method GET, and i've added HTTP Headers "Accept" "application/*****.1.0+json" which are the values specified by the API. I can call the API on my PC from other software and i get a success response.

I've installed the latest jar file from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core/1.19.4) and have tried using a tLibraryLoad to load this jar before the tRest client but get the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved by overwriting both jersey-client-1.4-6.0.0.jar and jersey-client-1.4-6.0.0.jar iwth the version from a colleague's PC.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're not using the right version of the jersey core library; Here's what the `tREST` looks like when you use it for the first time :

[image]

It will prompt you to install missing jars (not distributed by Talend), which are :

```
jersey-client-1.4.jar
jersey-core-1.4.jar
```

At which point you can just click "Download and install all modules available" and it will install them for you.

You don't need to use `tLibraryLoad` component, just delete all versions of these jars that might be present in the following locations, restart your studio, and you should get the prompt to install them again (as in the above screenshot) :

```
<Talend root folder>\configuration\.m2\repository\org\talend\libraries
<Talend root folder>\lib\java
```

Comment: I did have several versions installed 1.4, 1.9, 1.17, deleted, restarted and just installed 1.4 at the prompt but I'm still getting the same errors unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm that is weird.. It works perfectly for me. Could you upload an export of your job somewhere and share the link so I can test it ? (Without any sensitive information of course)

Comment: I've sent the job to a colleague and they can run the job ok. I'm going to try a fresh install of Talend, hopefully that will fix it.